# what happens if index creation is in progress and I'll send request to elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-emr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use elastic search 6.4 on AWS.

**Library:** RestHighLevelClient

Index/mapping creation may take few seconds/minutes. The [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html) tells us that when we send **PutMappingRequest** request, **AcknowledgedResponse**  indicates whether the operation completed before the timeout (**true**) or may take an effect sometime soon (**false**)

```
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("name");
request.mapping("type", JSON,  XContentType.JSON);
CreateIndexResponse response = client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
boolean result = response.isAcknowledged();
```

**My question:**

1)  if isAcknowledged is **false** , it means that index is not yet created. So what will happen if I send **JSON** to the elastic? Will elastic use my mapping that is **"in progress"** (**because of AcknowledgedResponse was fale** ) or will it create dynamically?

```
Map dataMap = convertValue(jsn, Map.class);
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, docType).id(key).source(dataMap);
client.index(indexRequest, DEFAULT);
```

2) 
 Is there any way to figure out whether my index is **"in-progress"** or not? **(without put mapping request, just to ask status of my index creation)**. A

3) When I send  create **IndexRequest** (when I send JSON document to elastic to save it), can't I pass mapping to this request? Just not to create mapping dynamically?